# Fermion - Antifermion (annihilation) scattering amplitude

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, scattering, fermions, feynman-diagrams

I'm trying to get the scattering of the diagrams described here in the "annihilation, part ii" (fermion/antifermion - scalar/scalar)
http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys624/agashe/F10/solutions/HW7.pdf
as part of an exercise I was given.

Following the Feynman rules, I've arrived to the following 
\begin{align} S_{fi} & = -ig(2\pi)^8 u(p_1) \gamma_5\int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{\gamma p - M} \gamma_5\upsilon(p_2)\delta^4 (P_f-P_i)
\\ & = -i g (2\pi)^4 u(p_1) \int \frac{d^4 p}{\gamma p - M} \upsilon(p_2)\delta^4 (P_f-P_i).\end{align}

The question is, did that amplitude come out right? How should I integrate that remaining integral? And is there an order to use the Feynman rules? There should be, since there are matrices around, but I don't get which.

Comment: re editing: this _might_ help:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11720/

Comment: it cannot be correct. Your amplitude must be a complex number. You must have an adjoint spinor (or adjoint anti-spinor) on the left.

Comment: but $u(p_1)$ and $v(p_2)$ are spinors, no?

Comment: @LowFieldTheory they are. And since there is no way to multiply two spinors, your answer is incorrect. But it is very close. There should be $\bar{u}(p_1)$ instead of $u(p_1)$ (the Dirac adjoint). The next step would be to take the average over input spins and sum over output spins, which would render a Lorentz-invariant scalar.